# How to scale properly Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, devops

In my project we have one AWS server running Jenkins Master + 1 Jenkins slave (2 executors)... and we need more  :-)

In order to augment our build power we have three options:

A) **Scale up**: Make AWS instance bigger and add more executors.

B) **Scale up**: Make AWS instance bigger and add another jenkins slave process.

C) **Scale out**: Create another AWS instance with a jenkins slave and connect it to master

We want to do B) as we are in a big organization and our current Jenkins Master has already access to every place he needs. Option C) "New server" is complicated as it needs more bureaucratic approvals that will take weeks.

So my questions are:

1. **Is there any technical issues in option B?**. Maybe the executors of each jenkins slave are not aware of the other slave executors?
2. In general, **what is the best approach to scale Jenkins?** Scaling up or scaling out?

Comment: cross-posted, but granted - on a (currently private) beta site: http://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/449/how-to-properly-scale-jenkins

Answer (score 0):

If I understands correctly you have Jenkins server with "master" node with 2 executors.
You are already using AWS or other scalable cloud infrastructure, opt. B is the way to go. I would advise to aim in solution in which you can dynamically add and remove nodes due to workload leaving "master" node (Jenkins server) for job management and reporting.

My tips:
- do not run any jobs on "master" (or at least limit as much as possible to preserve cpu power for job scheduling)
- create reusable images for nodes with configuration scripts for node setup(configuration being done by script or other deployment tool like Puppet or Docker to make sure nodes are identical).
- run/terminate nodes as needed (check swarm-plugin which simplify node configuration and connection to Jenkins)
- executors per node - depends on situation/instance performance and needs. Executors are not aware of others on same node which may cause problems if items done on executors are using shared resource from node. Simple example from Windows nodes&GUI tests - one executor can steal app focus from other. Be aware of such problems as this may lead to unstable build results. Dockers,VM and other means may help.

Comment: When you say "_I would advise to aim in solution in which you can dynamically add and remove nodes_" do you mean option C?

Comment: In fact A and B is the same as far as I understands, my proposal is going with C because of reasons above. 
More important,especially with AWS, pay attention about pricing for additional resources. CI will not be utilized in 100% (most probably as triggers for building&testing in your small project will not 24h/day) thus it may not be financial reasonable to have powerful CI instance being idle most of the time. Start nodes when needed may be cheeper and future-proof (need more executors? fire up more nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Found a good documentation for how this could be set up. 
https://d0.awsstatic.com/whitepapers/DevOps/Jenkins_on_AWS.pdf

There is a section that explains auto-recovery of the master instance as well.

I currently have ASG master instance with EFS attach to it. This provides scaling up/down of the master instance and some level of auto-recovery if the master instance do fail. With the slave, the EC2 plugin does wonders if you have the appropriate slave ami image set up. The slave ami would require git and java-1.8. If you have further requirements on your slave, do add them to the mix.

If there is further question around this set up, do feel free to leave a comment.